# Android:Problem in displaying text

Tags: java, android, textview

I got a bulk of text in a file that has to be displayed in the textview
The text should fit exactly in the screen and the remaining text in next page and so on !

Now the problem is how to get the position of the text when it has come to the end of the screen ?

Is there any possibility of getting the X and Y coordinates of the text ?

I did that by getting the width and height of the screen using window.getWidth() and window.getHeight() and tried calculating Pixel Vs Text and displayed accordingly..
But the problem with that was ,when the bufferreader encounters a new line, it is taking the new line as a single character and so the text is going out of the screen.

Forgive me if there are any mistakes or errors in the above problem !!!

Thanks,
Siva Kumar

Comment: I am also interested in its answer. in my case, I would like, how much text a textview will be capable of holding with its current settings, typeface and size.

Comment: i cud not get it completely...ur buffered reader encounter newline character and treat it as single character but why is it going out of screen ...what is the relation 2 it....

Comment: The new line gets displayed on the screen so the amount of the text the screen takes gets reduced ! consider the textview can take 450 characters say 12 lines that fits the screen.So, when a new line is encoutered, it takes it as a character and goes to next line to print.Now the number of lines for the screens gets reduced by 1

Comment: so u dont want 2 move 2 next line even when newline character appears.....m i right.......

Comment: i want to move to next line.. but the text that may go out of the screen has to be displayed in the next page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do one thing, I'm just guessing it.

We can take height of textview at runtime
we have font size
and space between 2 consecutive line

3rd parameter can be set in XML.

You can calculate space used by your text on the basis of these 2 above stated parameters and compare them with the height of textview.

I think you might able two find out, text is going out of screen or not.

Comment: Is there any possibility of getting the number of lines the text occupy in the textview ?

Comment: is its width constant???if not you can directly calculate on the basis of no. of new line characters appearing in text....

Comment: When the text is displayed continuosly you do not get the newlines right !!I mean, when the text reaches the end of the line it automatically goes to the next line which is not same as the new line... I need that line count !! but not finding the way to get that ..

Comment: thats why i asked is textviews width constant??if its not then it will shift 2 next line only in case of newline character.....ok now have 2 search it more....but a good question..;-)....